# Create a tunnel to my dedicated windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, tunneling, dedicated-server

I have a Win 2008 dedicated server. The remote access for MSSQL db is disabled. However I want to connect to it during development from my system. I need to create something like a tunnel from my lap so as to access it. I don't have static IP.

Another reason for mentioning about creating tunnel is that my server IP has been whitelisted with other server. The data must originate from my dedicated server then only I can do the testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So?

Add RRAS from Windows Features (Routing and Remote Access).

Set up VPN link.

I do the same - have some machines in Chicago and VPN out of them (out of them as I want them to be totally sealed off from the internet, I used KVM to set up the link).

Comment: did both of that. established VPN connection successfully.
what is the next step..?

Comment: Add routing rules etc. depending what you want to do actually network wise. I have no clue how your nwtwork loks like and at the end this is a site for pro admins, so if you can not set up simple network routing - this is not the place to learn. Ask concrete questions. But if you ahve set up that now you did create a tunnel, the rest is very depending on your network topology.